# How to show navigation bar options to specific users in moodle lms?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

Below is my code for showing an extra option in navigation-drawer of Moodle LMS account.

```
function local_report_extend_navigation(global_navigation $navigation)
```

{

```
$main_node = $navigation->add(get_string('pluginname', 'local_report'), '/local/report/');
$main_node->nodetype = 1;
$main_node->collapse = false;
$main_node->force_open = true;
$main_node->isexpandable = false;
$main_node->showinflatnavigation = true; 
// $main_node->icon = new pix_icon('i/settings', get_string('pluginname', 'local_report'));
$main_node->icon = new pix_icon('i/files', get_string('pluginname', 'local_report'));
```

}
The output for it is :
[This is the navigation-drawer. I want to show the Reports option to only admin, teacher and manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orZXO.png)

Can anyone let me know how to make this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a capability in your local plugin. In `local/report/db/access.php`

```
$capabilities = array(
    'local/report:canview' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
            'manager' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'teacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
            'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Then use something like this in your function.

```
if (!has_capability('local/report:canview', \context_system::instance())) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: now the report option is completely hidden

Comment: When you add a new capability you also need to update the plugin. So bump the version number so the capability is installed. Then use a user with that capability to test it.

Comment: I did as you said. The manager is having the access but whenever I logged in as a teacher ( editing ) the reports option is not visible. Only visible when I am an admin or a manager